How to retrieve full country name from address field
I'm using the Address field in Craft CMS 5, as detailed in the Craft CMS documentation. I need to display the full country name based on the countryCode provided by the Address field.
Currently, the Address field only provides a countryCode, and it seems there is no direct way to get the full country name. I understand I could use a lookup table or a plugin, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require either of these.
Why does Craft CMS 5 only provide the countryCode and not a country attribute that directly gives the full country name? Is there an existing native method or a built-in function in Craft CMS that can convert the countryCode to the full country name without resorting to external resources?

Craft 5.3 and 4.11 added a getCountry() method to address elements. This method returns a CommerceGuys\Addressing\Country\Country model, which (among other things) has a name property that can be used to access the country's full name:
In Twig:
{% set country = entry.someAddressField.one().country.name|default %}

PHP:
$country = $entry->someAddressField->one()?->getCountry()->name;

Check out the official docs or the original PR for more details.
Note that for Craft 4 and 5 versions earlier than 5.3 or 4.11, Steve Holland's answer works.

You'd need to call the Country Repository to fetch the Country itself. I found it in the Craft v4 docs here. I'm assuming it'd be the same for Craft v5
Twig
{# @var country CommerceGuys\Addressing\Country\Country #}
{% set country = craft.app.getAddresses().countryRepository.get('US') %}

PHP
/** @var CommerceGuys\Addressing\Country\Country $country **/
$country = Craft::$app->getAddresses()->countryRepository->get('US');

Just replace 'US' with your countryCode.
